tileserver-gl issue when running in container on gcloud behind nginx proxy
I have tileserver-gl running in a container on google cloud.  So far everything is good.  Success is indicated by being able to go to the tileserver-gl app page and see a preview of my data.
Next I use the directions here:  https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/internet-proxy-nginx-sidecar
to setup a proxy server in front of my tileserver-gl app.  The steps complete w/o error and I can view the tileserver-gl app page being served through the proxy.  However, the data preview is no longer visible, indicating something is not talking/connected correctly.
Here is my nginx.conf file.  Through the gcloud UI the nginx front end is configured to run at 8080 and the tileserver-gl app has environment vaiable 8888 defined.
####nginx.conf#####
server {
    # Listen at port 8080
    listen 8080; 

    # Server at localhost
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8888;

        # Various Headers to Ensure Tileserver-GL Generated URLs Visible
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        }
}


I tried setting up an identical architecture locally using docker-compose running separate containers for the nginx proxy and the app.  This worked perfectly. The issues arise when deploying this to gcloud.

The nginx.conf file you shared seems to indicate that the nginx server is listening on port 8080 and proxying requests to the tileserver-gl app is running on port 8888. The headers set in the configuration are essential for passing the necessary information to ensure proper communication between nginx and the tileserver-gl app.
You may consider checking again the network configuration to ensure that communication between nginx and tileserver-gl app are up and running and verify as well the ports are open and properly configured.
